# Show that $p$ and $q$ are not principal, but that $p^2$, $pq$ and $q^2$ are.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be the ﬁeld $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{−15})$, let $R = \mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$. Let $\alpha= \frac{-1+\sqrt{-15}}{2}$ and consider the prime ideals $p = (2,α)$ and $q = (17,α + 6)$ of $R$. Show that $p$ and $q$ are not principal, but that $p^2$, $pq$ and $q^2$ are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p$ is principal, then there's some $\beta$ such that $2$ and $\alpha$ are both multiples of $\beta$. Then the norm of $2$ and the norm of $\alpha$ are both multiples of the norm of $\beta$. From that, you can work out the possibilities for the norm of $\beta$, and then the possibilities for $\beta$ itself, and then eliminate the possibilities.

Similarly for $q$.

For the rest of the question, the first step is to calculate each of those products. You do that, then we'll have a look at the results if you still need help.